# When loading a DLL File, is the entry point of the DLL File also called?

Tags: windows, dll

I take an example for a question.

If a DLL file (is called A) is executed by some ways, I assume that 'A' loads some DLL file in system root.

One of these DLL files is called 'B' has entry point like DllMain function.

So if I run 'A', will entry point of 'B' be called as well?

If it is called, Can I control the parameters of DllMain?

Thank you for your interest in this question.

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

I answer my own question :)

**examples**

DllMain function :

```
DllMain(...) {
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "in DLL1 function DllMain()", "test", 0);
    hello()
    ...
}
```

hello function (not exported function) :

```
hello() {
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "in DLL1 function hello()", "test", 0);
}
```

exported function (exported function) :

```
exported() {
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "in DLL1 function exported()", "test", 0);
}
```

and message box is popuped following order:

DllMain() -> hello() -> exported() -> DllMain() -> hello()

but I don't know why DllMain function is called finally.

Comment: `DllMain` gets both "attach" and "detach" notifications -- the parameters let you distinguish.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you load the DLL.

- If it is linked via the import table, it will be loaded and its `DllMain` executed when its dependency is needed (before actually loading the dependency).
- If it is loaded via `LoadLibrary`, its `DllMain` will be executed.
- If it is loaded via `LoadLibraryEx` and any of `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE`, `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE` or `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE` flags are used, `DllMain` will be skipped.

More details can be found in [the `LoadLibraryEx` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexa).